# User's info not showing up on Realtime Database (java)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I was able to connect users to firebase with email, but my Realtime Database is still showing- "https://dogsinfo-69ae3-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/:null" even when saving their info like name, age etc'.

I don't know what else to do for it to show users' info instead of null.

The code:

```
public class Owner extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText etemail;
  private EditText etpassword;
  private EditText repassword;
  private EditText OwnersName;
  private EditText DogsBreed;
  private EditText DogName;
  private EditText Address;
  private EditText DogsAge;
  private EditText ettime;
  private EditText AdditionalRequests;
  private RadioButton Comfterbul;
  private RadioButton Friend;

  Button SignIn;
  private DatabaseReference database;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.owner_main);
    etemail = findViewById(R.id.email);
    etpassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
    OwnersName = findViewById(R.id.ownersName);
    repassword = findViewById(R.id.etrepassword);
    DogsBreed = findViewById(R.id.DogsBreed2);
    DogName = findViewById(R.id.DogsName);
    Address = findViewById(R.id.Address2);
    DogsAge = findViewById(R.id.DogsAge2);
    ettime = findViewById(R.id.time1);
    AdditionalRequests = findViewById(R.id.AdditionalRequests2);
    Comfterbul = findViewById(R.id.comfterbul2);
    Friend = findViewById(R.id.Friend2);
    SignIn = findViewById(R.id.SignIn);
  }

  public void savename(View view) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Owners name");
    myRef.setValue(OwnersName.getText().toString());
  }
  public void saveDogsBreed(View view) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("breed");
    myRef.setValue(DogsBreed.getText().toString());
  }
  public void saveDogName(View view) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Dogs Name");
    myRef.setValue(DogName.getText().toString());
  }
  public void createAccount(View view) {
    String email = etemail.getText().toString();
    String password = etpassword.getText().toString();
    String etrepassword = repassword.getText().toString();
    String ownersName = OwnersName.getText().toString();
    String DogsBreed2 = DogsBreed.getText().toString();
    String DogsName = DogName.getText().toString();
    String Address2 = Address.getText().toString();
    String DogsAge2 = DogsAge.getText().toString();
    String time1 = ettime.getText().toString();
    String AdditionalRequests2 = AdditionalRequests.getText().toString();
    boolean comfterbul2 = Comfterbul.isChecked();
    boolean Friend2 = Friend.isChecked();
    createAccountInFirebase(email, password, etrepassword, ownersName, DogsBreed2, DogsName, Address2, DogsAge2, time1, AdditionalRequests2, comfterbul2, Friend2);
  }
  public void createAccountInFirebase(String email, String password, String etrepassword, String ownersName, String DogsBreed2, String DogsName, String Address2, String DogsAge2, String time1, String AdditionalRequests2, boolean comfterbul2, boolean Friend2) {
      FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(Owner.this, new OnCompleteListener\ < AuthResult\ > () {
        @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task\ < AuthResult\ > task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) { //User is successfully registered.
            UserOwner userOwner = new UserOwner(email, password, etrepassword, ownersName, DogsBreed2, DogsName, Address2, DogsAge2, time1, AdditionalRequests2, comfterbul2, Friend2) Toast.makeText(Owner.this, "Registration is successful", # # Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Owner.this, LogIn.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(Owner.this, "Registration failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: If you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check the logcat output for relevant messages from Firebase, what does it show?

Comment: Have you tried to attach listeners to the operations that write data to the database? Please respond using @AlexMamo